# Tracking Multiple Vehicles On A Map

Tags: dictionary, geolocation

I want to track multiple vehicles on an open source map. I doesn't matter if it is in Google Maps or something else. What I want to do is like this project:
http://mbus.pts.umich.edu/index.php

I want to see in real-time how the cars change their positon. Therefor I get the GPS from the cars. Is this possible without a Google Maps Licence? Also with several cars? And are there any other examples showing how to manage this?

It would be great if someone could help me! I just cannot find any other examples or tutorials.

Comment: This is a bit too broad (however interesting) for Stack Overflow. If you have an actual implementation issue, we'd love to help!